# TLSv1.2+BouncyCastle+Apache httpclient 4.4

Tags: ssl, bouncycastle, java-6

With reference to the solution provided in [How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6/35023945#3502394), is it possible to use the TSLSocketConnectionFactory with the Apache HttpClient4.4.

Regards,
j

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use TSLSocketConnectionFactory with HttpClient like following:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(new TLSSocketConnectionFactory(), new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, null, new DefaultHostnameVerifier());
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sf)
            .build();
```

You may need to change some of the SSLSession method implementations at the TSLSocketConnectionFactory.

In my case, when I tried to use it with HttpClient, I had to change the following:

At SSLSocket() implementation:

```
@Override
public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {          
    // return null;
    return new String[]{""};
}

@Override
public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
    // return null;
    return new String[]{""};
 }
```

At SSLSession() implementation:

```
 @Override
 public String getProtocol() {
 // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    return null;
 }
 @Override
 public String getProtocol() {
 // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    return "";
 }
 @Override
 public String getCipherSuite() {
 // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    return "":
 }
```

Comment: The class javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier is private in JDK 1.6u45,so it can not be used. Or are you using some other DefaultHostnameVerifier ?