# TSLv1.1 support for Apache camel jetty componenet

Tags: java, apache-camel, bouncycastle

I am developing an application to send HTTPS post request to URLs using Apache camel jetty component. I am using java 1.6_45 java version to run the application. But as java 1.6 does not support TLSv1.1, my request is processed using TLSv1.0. How could I get TLSv1.1 support without changing the java version ?

Is it enough to change the java security provider to bouncy castle in java.security file ?

Answer (score 0):

TSLv1.1 has apparently been implemented in Java 1.6_111 and later.

Source:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Note that updates to Java 1.6 after Update 45 are only available to customers with an Oracle Java support contract.

Alternatively - [How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6) - includes answers that say how to use Bouncy Castle to get TLSv1.2 support, and TLSv1.1 probably follows a similar pattern.