# Java 1.6 and TLS 1.1

Tags: java, ssl, https

(note: this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6))

We know that with the non-free Java 1.6_111 update, Java 1.6 can support TLS 1.1 with HTTPS. My question is: should I **compile** my program with Java 6 111 or just use java 6 111 with the -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1 switch?

Note: I've tried the latter and it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use Java 8.

Comment: Isn't it dependent upon the runtime / JVM ?

Comment: JDK 6 and 7 have both passed the end of their support lives.  Everyone should be using JDK 8.

Comment: Yep, I know I should use Java 8, but for some time I'm stuck with Java 1.6 (we're upgrading our application, but it's a slow process). Can someone answer the question?

Comment: You don't need to upgrade your application to use Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code (including libraries you call) is using something like `new URL("https://xxx").connect()` and NOT `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` directly? Only the former use the `https.` properties.

If using JSSE level, I don't pay for extended support and so don't have the code (or source, which IIRC for 6 didn't include crypto anyway), but [the release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#R160_111) only talk about selection by explicit call to `.setEnabledProtocols` (in code). The [release notes for **115 b32**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview-156328.html#6u115-b32) additionally say

> The new jdk.tls.client.protocols System Property may also be used to control the protocols in use for a TLS connection. (JDK-8151183)

and 'new' suggests this does not work in 111, but you could try it.

If you do make the code change to call `.setEnabledProtocols` the method itself already existed, only the argument value changed, so you can *compile* against any JDK6 and run on 6u111. (But if you unit-test and/or debug on the compile system, you presumably do need 6u111 for those.)