# Enabling TLS 1.2 in java 1.6

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, ws-security

I'm using jdk1.6 and tomcat6. I need to enable TLS 1.2. I can't upgrade either jdk or tomcat. I tried to change protocol in server.xml in tomcat but it did not work.  Please suggest.

Comment: JSSE only started supporting TLS 1.1 and 1.2 with Java 7 - so it seems you are out of luck. There might be ways with implementing special socket factories and plugging in different crypto-providers but that seems more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

You have some trouble into your post.
In fact, I think you want to said Tomcat 6 and not Tomcat 1.6.

The trouble is not tomcat but jdk1.6, this version doesn't implement TLS 1.2 but TLS 1.1.

You can found some work around on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6).

[Some more information from oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https)