# TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 not available in list of available protocols from SSLSocket

Tags: java

I wrote a code in java to get list of supported protocols. 
Case 1.
This code when runs at my local returns protocols: SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
And I can decide which protocol to use.
My Local environment is:
Windows 7, jdk1.7.0_45

Case 2.
When I run same code on 2 separate linux machines (java 1.7.0_40-b43 & java 1.6.0_41) and both return only SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1

Java code:

```
    if (!(socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        return socket;
    }
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socket;
    for (String protocol : sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols()) {
            System.out.println(protocol);
    }
```

Any idea what needs to be done to get TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 as supported protocols in Case 2 above.

Thanks

Comment: which java providers are you using? oracle and openjdk?

Comment: Java by oracle, For jdk 1.7 it is not a problem now - I figured out things wrong at my end, but for jdk 1.6 I am still not getting TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 as available protocols.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6

Comment: TLS 1.1 is available in oracle java 6 update 111, and TLS 1.2, in java 6 update 121

Comment: Right, I have an old version. Many thanks