# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake exception

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, http-post, sslhandshakeexception

**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake** Exception when trying to post to below url:

***https://testapi.title365.com/KeystoneB2B/OrdersService.aspx***

```
package com.visionetsystems.vtp.http.client;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SSLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SSLTest().test();
    }

    private void test() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
        try{
            String httpsURL = "https://testapi.title365.com/KeystoneB2B/OrdersService.aspx";
            URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
            InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }   
            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Stacktrace:**

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
  Valid from Wed Oct 25 04:36:00 EDT 2006 until Sat Oct 25 04:36:00 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 1 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 1 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Fri Jun 25 18:23:48 EDT 1999 until Tue Jun 25 18:23:48 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x344ed55720d5edec49f42fce37db2b6d
  Valid from Thu Nov 16 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2, OU=T-TeleSec Trust Center, O=Deutsche Telekom AG, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2, OU=T-TeleSec Trust Center, O=Deutsche Telekom AG, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x26
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 08:11:00 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 19:59:00 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x374ad243
  Valid from Tue May 25 12:09:40 EDT 1999 until Sat May 25 12:39:40 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Universal CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Thu Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2004 until Sun Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TC TrustCenter Universal CA I, OU=TC TrustCenter Universal CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=TC TrustCenter Universal CA I, OU=TC TrustCenter Universal CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1da200010002ecb76080788db606
  Valid from Wed Mar 22 10:54:28 EST 2006 until Wed Dec 31 17:59:59 EST 2025

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2, OU=T-Systems Trust Center, O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Wed Oct 01 06:40:14 EDT 2008 until Sat Oct 01 19:59:59 EDT 2033

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x9b7e0649a33e62b9d5ee90487129ef57
  Valid from Thu Sep 30 20:00:00 EDT 1999 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 2 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Fri Jun 25 20:19:54 EDT 1999 until Tue Jun 25 20:19:54 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
  Valid from Thu Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AddTrust Class 1 CA Root, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Issuer:  CN=AddTrust Class 1 CA Root, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 30 06:38:31 EDT 2000 until Sat May 30 06:38:31 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Issuer:  CN=AddTrust External CA Root, OU=AddTrust External TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 30 06:48:38 EDT 2000 until Sat May 30 06:48:38 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Issuer:  CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x85bd4bf3d8dae369f694d75fc3a54423
  Valid from Wed Jul 07 13:05:00 EDT 1999 until Sat Jul 06 19:59:59 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x35def4cf
  Valid from Sat Aug 22 12:41:51 EDT 1998 until Wed Aug 22 12:41:51 EDT 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Issuer:  CN=Chambers of Commerce Root - 2008, O=AC Camerfirma S.A., SERIALNUMBER=A82743287, L=Madrid (see current address at www.camerfirma.com/address), C=EU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xa3da427ea4b1aeda
  Valid from Fri Aug 01 08:29:50 EDT 2008 until Sat Jul 31 08:29:50 EDT 2038

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x6170cb498c5f984529e7b0a6d9505b7a
  Valid from Thu Sep 30 20:00:00 EDT 1999 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Issuer:  CN=AAA Certificate Services, O=Comodo CA Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 2003 until Sun Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 1999 until Sun Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2004 until Thu Jun 29 13:39:16 EDT 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4cc7eaaa983e71d39310f83d3a899192
  Valid from Sun May 17 20:00:00 EDT 1998 until Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xce7e0e517d846fe8fe560fc1bf03039
  Valid from Thu Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Sun Nov 09 19:00:00 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x40000000001154b5ac394
  Valid from Tue Sep 01 08:00:00 EDT 1998 until Fri Jan 28 07:00:00 EST 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7dd9fe07cfa81eb7107967fba78934c6
  Valid from Sun May 17 20:00:00 EDT 1998 until Tue Aug 01 19:59:59 EDT 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=QuoVadis Root CA 3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Issuer:  CN=QuoVadis Root CA 3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x5c6
  Valid from Fri Nov 24 14:11:23 EST 2006 until Mon Nov 24 14:06:44 EST 2031

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Certum CA, O=Unizeto Sp. z o.o., C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=Certum CA, O=Unizeto Sp. z o.o., C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x10020
  Valid from Tue Jun 11 06:46:39 EDT 2002 until Fri Jun 11 06:46:39 EDT 2027

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x400000000010f8626e60d
  Valid from Fri Dec 15 03:00:00 EST 2006 until Wed Dec 15 03:00:00 EST 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x36122296c5e338a520a1d25f4cd70954
  Valid from Wed Jul 31 20:00:00 EDT 1996 until Fri Jan 01 18:59:59 EST 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=*.KeyStoneB2B.com, O="Archwell Solutions, LLC", L=Jacksonville, ST=Florida, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc69f68001015407ee9d8844aa114f30
  Valid from Sun Dec 20 19:00:00 EST 2015 until Wed Jan 04 07:00:00 EST 2017

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Chambers of Commerce Root, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, C=EU
  Issuer:  CN=Chambers of Commerce Root, OU=http://www.chambersign.org, O=AC Camerfirma SA CIF A82743287, C=EU
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 30 12:13:43 EDT 2003 until Wed Sep 30 12:13:44 EDT 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4a538c28
  Valid from Tue Jul 07 13:25:54 EDT 2009 until Sat Dec 07 12:55:54 EST 2030

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Class 3P Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Issuer:  CN=Class 3P Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xbf5cdbb6f21c6ec04deb7a023b36e879
  Valid from Wed Jul 07 13:10:00 EDT 1999 until Sat Jul 06 19:59:59 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18dad19e267de8bb4a2158cdcc6b3b4a
  Valid from Tue Nov 07 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x401ac46421b31321030ebbe4121ac51d
  Valid from Tue Apr 01 20:00:00 EDT 2008 until Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
  Valid from Tue May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2002 until Sat May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2022

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x3c9131cb1ff6d01b0e9ab8d044bf12be
  Valid from Sun Jan 28 19:00:00 EST 1996 until Wed Aug 02 19:59:59 EDT 2028

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Issuer:  CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x444c0
  Valid from Wed Oct 22 08:07:37 EDT 2008 until Mon Dec 31 07:07:37 EST 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Sep 30 00:20:49 EDT 2003 until Sat Sep 30 00:20:49 EDT 2023

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Sonera Class1 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Issuer:  CN=Sonera Class1 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x24
  Valid from Fri Apr 06 06:49:13 EDT 2001 until Tue Apr 06 06:49:13 EDT 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, O="The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Jun 29 13:06:20 EDT 2004 until Thu Jun 29 13:06:20 EDT 2034

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d336252567c989
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 13:28:50 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 13:36:58 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d3362afe650afd
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 14:10:42 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 14:19:22 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18acb56afd69b6153a636cafdafac4a1
  Valid from Sun Nov 26 19:00:00 EST 2006 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4000000000121585308a2
  Valid from Wed Mar 18 06:00:00 EDT 2009 until Sun Mar 18 06:00:00 EDT 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x8b5b75568454850b00cfaf3848ceb1a4
  Valid from Thu Sep 30 20:00:00 EDT 1999 until Wed Jul 16 19:59:59 EDT 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=America Online Root Certification Authority 1, O=America Online Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Tue May 28 02:00:00 EDT 2002 until Thu Nov 19 15:43:00 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA2, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Fri May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2009 until Tue May 29 01:00:39 EDT 2029

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Issuer:  CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
  Valid from Tue Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1996 until Thu Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x15ac6e9419b2794b41f627a9c3180f1f
  Valid from Tue Apr 01 20:00:00 EDT 2008 until Tue Dec 01 18:59:59 EST 2037

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1b6
  Valid from Fri Aug 14 10:50:00 EDT 1998 until Wed Aug 14 19:59:00 EDT 2013

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Object, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Object, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d3362de0b35f1b
  Valid from Fri Jul 09 14:31:20 EDT 1999 until Tue Jul 09 14:40:36 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=UTN - DATACorp SGC, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=UTN - DATACorp SGC, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500021b411d32a6806a9ad69
  Valid from Thu Jun 24 14:57:21 EDT 1999 until Mon Jun 24 15:06:30 EDT 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Issuer:  CN=Sonera Class2 CA, O=Sonera, C=FI
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1d
  Valid from Fri Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2001 until Tue Apr 06 03:29:40 EDT 2021

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2e6a000100021fd752212c115c3b
  Valid from Thu Jan 12 09:38:43 EST 2006 until Wed Dec 31 17:59:59 EST 2025

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1484192759 bytes = { 167, 186, 220, 19, 71, 126, 141, 1, 137, 160, 103, 171, 233, 24, 232, 150, 156, 190, 228, 44, 61, 13, 200, 107, 16, 148, 57, 225 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 177
0000: 01 00 00 AD 03 01 58 77   FC F7 A7 BA DC 13 47 7E  ......Xw......G.
0010: 8D 01 89 A0 67 AB E9 18   E8 96 9C BE E4 2C 3D 0D  ....g........,=.
0020: C8 6B 10 94 39 E1 00 00   46 00 04 00 05 00 2F 00  .k..9...F...../.
0030: 35 C0 02 C0 04 C0 05 C0   0C C0 0E C0 0F C0 07 C0  5...............
0040: 09 C0 0A C0 11 C0 13 C0   14 00 33 00 39 00 32 00  ..........3.9.2.
0050: 38 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D C0   08 C0 12 00 16 00 13 00  8...............
0060: 09 00 15 00 12 00 03 00   08 00 14 00 11 00 FF 01  ................
0070: 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34 00   32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00  ..>...4.2.......
0080: 13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B 00  ................
0090: 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E 00   0F 00 10 00 11 00 02 00  ................
00A0: 12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   08 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00                                                 .
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 177
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 173
0000: 01 03 01 00 84 00 00 00   20 00 00 04 01 00 80 00  ........ .......
0010: 00 05 00 00 2F 00 00 35   00 C0 02 00 C0 04 01 00  ..../..5........
0020: 80 00 C0 05 00 C0 0C 00   C0 0E 00 C0 0F 00 C0 07  ................
0030: 05 00 80 00 C0 09 06 00   40 00 C0 0A 07 00 C0 00  ........@.......
0040: C0 11 00 C0 13 00 C0 14   00 00 33 00 00 39 00 00  ..........3..9..
0050: 32 00 00 38 00 00 0A 07   00 C0 00 C0 03 02 00 80  2..8............
0060: 00 C0 0D 00 C0 08 00 C0   12 00 00 16 00 00 13 00  ................
0070: 00 09 06 00 40 00 00 15   00 00 12 00 00 03 02 00  ....@...........
0080: 80 00 00 08 00 00 14 00   00 11 00 00 FF 58 77 FC  .............Xw.
0090: F7 A7 BA DC 13 47 7E 8D   01 89 A0 67 AB E9 18 E8  .....G.....g....
00A0: 96 9C BE E4 2C 3D 0D C8   6B 10 94 39 E1           ....,=..k..9.
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 173
[Raw write]: length = 175
0000: 80 AD 01 03 01 00 84 00   00 00 20 00 00 04 01 00  .......... .....
0010: 80 00 00 05 00 00 2F 00   00 35 00 C0 02 00 C0 04  ....../..5......
0020: 01 00 80 00 C0 05 00 C0   0C 00 C0 0E 00 C0 0F 00  ................
0030: C0 07 05 00 80 00 C0 09   06 00 40 00 C0 0A 07 00  ..........@.....
0040: C0 00 C0 11 00 C0 13 00   C0 14 00 00 33 00 00 39  ............3..9
0050: 00 00 32 00 00 38 00 00   0A 07 00 C0 00 C0 03 02  ..2..8..........
0060: 00 80 00 C0 0D 00 C0 08   00 C0 12 00 00 16 00 00  ................
0070: 13 00 00 09 06 00 40 00   00 15 00 00 12 00 00 03  ......@.........
0080: 02 00 80 00 00 08 00 00   14 00 00 11 00 00 FF 58  ...............X
0090: 77 FC F7 A7 BA DC 13 47   7E 8D 01 89 A0 67 AB E9  w......G.....g..
00A0: 18 E8 96 9C BE E4 2C 3D   0D C8 6B 10 94 39 E1     ......,=..k..9.
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.visionetsystems.vtp.http.client.SSLTest.test(SSLTest.java:26)
    at com.visionetsystems.vtp.http.client.SSLTest.main(SSLTest.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Already tried replacing the JCE Jurisdiction Policy Files with no luck :(

**Can someone please help?**

Answer (score 0):

The site [supports only TLS 1.2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=testapi.title365.com&s=50.18.201.62) and not TLS 1.0. You are using Java 6 which only supports TLS 1.0 as the highest version. This means that server and client have no common TLS protocol version and thus can not communicate. TLS 1.2 is only supported by default with Java 8 and with some fiddling in Java 7 but definitely not with your Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to do it in Java 6 since I can't upgrade my application.

Comment: @askquestiontosof: [How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6)

Comment: Added bouncy castle but it didn't work. Tried java7 as well and got the same exception. It only worked with Java8. Is there any other way to do it in java6 as bouncy castle didn't help?

Comment: @askquestiontosof: as far as I know there is no way.