# Https web service call failure

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, jax-ws

We have implemented webservice call using `JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6` now problem comes when we enable `https` webservice call stops reaching server and java reports following error,

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Async IO
>   operation failed (3), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource
>   or device is no longer available.

Now I have tested this within `SoapUI` and response from the service is received there.

Looked into various solution where it tells us to provide timeout settings but nothing seems work.

```
 @WebEndpoint(name = "RulesSoap")
    public RulesSoap getRulesSoap() {
        ((BindingProvider)super.getPort(new QName("urn:decision:Rules", "RulesSoap"), RulesSoap.class)).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", 1000);
        ((BindingProvider)super.getPort(new QName("urn:decision:Rules", "RulesSoap"), RulesSoap.class)).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 1000);
        return super.getPort(new QName("urn:decision:Rules", "RulesSoap"), RulesSoap.class);
    }
```

And just for information JAX-WS implementation is following few simple lines, 
of course we submit all necessary data into respective stubs and all but I am not submitting here because our `http` calls are getting through,

```
Rules rules = new Rules(new URL(url), new QName("urn:decision:Rules", "Rules"));
RulesSoap rulesSoap = rules.getRulesSoap();
CorticonResponse response = rulesSoap.processRequest(request);
```

**Note :** Our application server `WebSphere Application Server` and Version `7.0.0.19`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of efforts we resolved this. I will provide steps if anything related to this happens how to find root cause,

**Step 1 :**
First of all we enabled soap tracing in `WebSphere Application Server` by following setting,

> Admin Console > Servers > Server Types > WebSphere Application Servers >
>   {your server} > Troubleshooting > Change Log Detail Levels > Runtime

In run time please put this , `*=info: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.*=all`

This step will create `trace.log` file in your logs folder.
Now any web service request which goes out of your server will add logs to this file and necessary props like endpoint, request, response etc.

**Step 2 :**
Reading this `trace.log` file we found following endpoint,

```
PropertyValid 1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.PropertyValidator validate validate property=(javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address) with value=(http://uxm.solutions.lnet.com:9445/axis/dswsdl/Rules/1/0)    
HTTPConnectio 3 resetConnection : http://uxm.solutions.lnet.com:9445/axis/dswsdl/Rules/1/0 Persistent : true
```

Now if you notice here that our soap has endpoint address `javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address` where protocol is still using `http` which causes to fail ssl handshake.

**Step 3 :**
**Solution** for this is to override endpoint inside your soap stubs which can be implemented by adding following line,

```
RulesSoap rulesSoap = rules.getRulesSoap();   
((BindingProvider)rulesSoap).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://uxm.solutions.lnet.com:9445/axis/dswsdl/Rules/1/0");
```

**Conclusion :**
So here is what i think even we pass `https` url while we are creating objects but still does not  take this `https` url on runtime, to me this looks like stubs creation issue with `JAX-WS`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What protocol /ciphers are you using? You have mentioned there is connection to webservice on WAS7 with JDK6 and Java 6 does not support TLS1.2 (and TLS1.1 only from certain fixpack).

See this:
[How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6)