# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Jrockit java1.6

Tags: ssl, httpclient, tls1.2, java-6, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to write an httpClient to connect to a rest webservice. I am getting the `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

I have configured the certificate in the keystore. I am using Jrockit jdk 1.6 and the server excepts only TLSv1.2. Below is the stack trace:

```
   Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1485544170 bytes = { 220, 193, 1, 205, 129, 63, 94, 33, 93, 117, 56, 16, 231, 164, 188, 129, 155, 13, 142, 31, 171, 64, 3, 110, 98, 169, 114, 221 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL
_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_
WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 75
0000: 01 00 00 47 03 01 59 8C   9B EA DC C1 01 CD 81 3F  ...G..Y........?
0010: 5E 21 5D 75 38 10 E7 A4   BC 81 9B 0D 8E 1F AB 40  ^!]u8..........@
0020: 03 6E 62 A9 72 DD 00 00   20 00 04 00 05 00 2F 00  .nb.r... ...../.
0030: 33 00 32 00 0A 00 16 00   13 00 09 00 15 00 12 00  3.2.............
0040: 03 00 08 00 14 00 11 00   FF 01 00                 ...........
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 101
0000: 01 03 01 00 3C 00 00 00   20 00 00 04 01 00 80 00  ....<... .......
0010: 00 05 00 00 2F 00 00 33   00 00 32 00 00 0A 07 00  ..../..3..2.....
0020: C0 00 00 16 00 00 13 00   00 09 06 00 40 00 00 15  ............@...
0030: 00 00 12 00 00 03 02 00   80 00 00 08 00 00 14 00  ................
0040: 00 11 00 00 FF 59 8C 9B   EA DC C1 01 CD 81 3F 5E  .....Y........?^
0050: 21 5D 75 38 10 E7 A4 BC   81 9B 0D 8E 1F AB 40 03  !]u8..........@.
0060: 6E 62 A9 72 DD                                     nb.r.
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101
[Raw write]: length = 103
0000: 80 65 01 03 01 00 3C 00   00 00 20 00 00 04 01 00  .e....<... .....
0010: 80 00 00 05 00 00 2F 00   00 33 00 00 32 00 00 0A  ....../..3..2...
0020: 07 00 C0 00 00 16 00 00   13 00 00 09 06 00 40 00  ..............@.
0030: 00 15 00 00 12 00 00 03   02 00 80 00 00 08 00 00  ................
0040: 14 00 00 11 00 00 FF 59   8C 9B EA DC C1 01 CD 81  .......Y........
0050: 3F 5E 21 5D 75 38 10 E7   A4 BC 81 9B 0D 8E 1F AB  ?^!]u8..........
0060: 40 03 6E 62 A9 72 DD                               @.nb.r.
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: Unknown-3.3 Alert, length = 2
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', called closeSocket()
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', called close()
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:262)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:357)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at eyemed.luxvisioncareproxy.service.client.uhc.UHCClient.UHCRestClient(UHCClient.java:137)
        at eyemed.luxvisioncare.flow.services.ExtendedMemberSearchFlowService.getExtendedMemberDetails(ExtendedMemberSearchFlowService.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:878)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1280)
        at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1356)
        at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
        at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
        at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
        at org.springframework.binding.expression.ognl.OgnlExpression.getValue(OgnlExpression.java:85)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.DefaultTransitionCriteria.test(DefaultTransitionCriteria.java:48)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.matches(Transition.java:184)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionSet.getTransition(TransitionSet.java:127)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.getRequiredTransition(TransitionableState.java:91)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent
    enter code here
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Java 1.6 does not support TLSv1.2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6