# TLSv1.2 using IBM Java 1.6 Received fatel alert: handshak_failure

Tags: tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to establish a TLSv1. 2 connection using IBM Java 1.6. It's throwing the following exception.

> Exception:  Received fatel alert:  handshake_failure

But I can achieve the same thing in Oracle java 1.7.  I need to achieve this in IBM Java 1.6. It seems like need some changes in IBM policy files.  Please advice me to resolve this issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use TLS 1.2 in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364100/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-java-6)

Comment: @Kzrystof It's not duplicate.