# How to avoid Diffie-Hellman for SSL connections with Java/Netty?

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I am using Netty as backend in a Java-based Usenet client. The library is working fine, however, in some circumstances I can't connect to a remote server via SSL, because of exactly this error:

[Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)

Unfortunately, it seems that for whatever reason this Java error still has not been fixed yet. And since the remote server is not under my control, I need a workaround here. One such "solution", according to the link above, is to avoid DH during SSL handshake at all (not very pretty, but maybe better than nothing).

However, I am no SSL expert, so I am not really sure how I can implement that within Netty; or better: within my solution that is based on Netty. By now I am creating connections as this:

```java
// configure the Netty client
ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(clSockChannelFactory);

// configure the pipeline factory
bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(channelPipelineFactory);
bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);
bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory", 
          new AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory());

// start the connection attempt
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, port);
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(isa);
...
channel = future.getChannel();
...
```

Ok, that's fine, but where can I disable cipher suites before I connect the SSL socket, as desribed in the thread above?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Kind regards, Matthias

PS: By the way, any ideas why this problem has not been addressed in Java yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Netty, but I would suggest following the approach in the [secure chat example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientPipelineFactory.html).

I'm not sure what default SSL/TLS keys/trust settings you have, but if you don't have a custom `SSLContext`, try `SSLContext.getDefault()`.

Then, create an `SSLEngine` using [`SSLContext.createSSLEngine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#createSSLEngine%28%29). On this `SSLEngine`, you should be able to [enable the cipher suites you want](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#setEnabledCipherSuites%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). Assuming you're using the Oracle JRE (or OpenJDK), you'll find the [list of cipher suites in the Sun Provider documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider).

After this (this is the Netty-specific part), set an `SslHandler` using something like this (see Netty example):

```
pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
```