# HttpURLConnection getContentType not working for SSL connection

Tags: java, http, https

For a specific HTTPS URL, the following java code does not correctly retrieve the Content-Type:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
String mimeType = connection.getContentType();

if (mimeType == null) throw new Exception("Could not detemine mimetype for remote URL.");
```

However if I curl the URL with -I, I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Jul 2014 00:50:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Additionally, if I run the Java code without the URL being HTTPS, getContentType does retrieve the mime type successfully.  Finally, the Java code does work for other servers that are connected to with HTTPS.

Comment: So there is something odd at that specific URL. Server configuration. Nothing you can do about it at the client except cope with a missing content-type.

Comment: Right but what on the server would cause this?  Also why can curl see the header but java.net does not?

Comment: Have you used wireshark (or similar tool) to see what going over the wire? Have you tried getting the response code before getting the content type? Is it possible that curl and java provide are providing different values in the Accept header in the request?

Answer (score 0):

The URL was using AES-256 SSL and I was running into this:  [Java SSL DH Keypair Generation - Prime Size Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442547/java-ssl-dh-keypair-generation-prime-size-error)

I'll either have to update my java or use bouncy castle.