# Jenkins build fails due to "Could not generate DH keypair"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have one project that could build with java 8, but build fails with java 7. 
Here's jenkins build fail message. I google it and found it seems a JDK bug. Is there any workaround for it ? Because I don't have permission to change the jenkins server environment.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive) -> [Help 1]
```

[Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)

Comment: The SO you have linked itself has a workaround in the accepted answer. Didn't it work?

Comment: That wordaround seems need to change the jenkins server, but I don't have permission to change anything on that machine.