# Charles Proxy SSL debug error, SSL: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

Tags: ssl, proxy, charles-proxy, network-traffic

When I scraping web pages with SSL connection I got error "SSL: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair" in Charles Proxy. I have followed steps showing here,
[Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)
but it doesn't help me.
Anyone know how to avoid this
thank you