# Database connectivity using mssql2008 and jdbc

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, eclipse-kepler

So I have setup my code like so

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HRDB;
            String user = "sa";
            String pass = "r";

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);

            return conn;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            return null;
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to connect to the database I get the following exceptions.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair".
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following question for some information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception

Comment: It turns out that this issue is with Windows 10 not with anyone of the above.

Comment: Can you please let me and the others know on how have you identified it? May be edit your question to add your answer or answer your own question, so that it is helpful for the others too!