# Realex Redirect 1.2TLS | Opencart v2.0.1.1

Tags: apache, opencart, tls1.2, realex-payments-api

I'm having an issue with a Realex Redirect payment extension on Opencart. The payment goes through fine but Realex is giving the message:

"Your transaction has been successful but there was a problem connecting back to the merchants web site Please contact the merchant and advise them that you received this error message"

I have asked Realex to provide a request log:

2017-07-12 16:56:56.687 Trying to connecting to return URL : /index.php?route=payment/realex/notify

2017-07-12 16:56:56.867 Trying to connecting to return URL : /index.php?route=payment/realex/notify

2017-07-12 16:56:56.943 Trying to connecting to return URL : /index.php?route=payment/realex/notify

2017-07-12 16:56:57.017 Retry attempts :3

2017-07-12 16:56:57.017 Detail error message from apache http client :java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

2017-07-12 16:56:57.020 Http Status Code:0

It had been redirecting back to the notification URL before the migration to the server to support TLS 1.2, what could the issue be here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer would be relevant: [Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)

Your Realex account manager should also be able to advise on compatible TLS certificates.

Best,

Seán

Comment: Thanks Seán, so is it the domain's SSL that isn't compatible with TLS 1.2?

Comment: Can I just confirm you are targeting: https://pay.realexpayments.com/pay? The issue seems to be caused by the domain TLS Certificate and an incompatibility with the version of Java the HPP runs on.

Answer (score -1):

This is notify url issue "/index.php?route=payment/realex/notify".

This URL is not full url. it should be like this.
http://example.com/index.php?route=payment/realex/notify

So this is Realex extension issue. Please contact to support of Realex Redirect payment

Comment: I think TwistedPixel88 just removed their domain or that's what the log shows. If the Notify URL was" /index.php?route=payment/realex/notify" we'd be getting a very different error.