# java mail program doesn't send mails anymore

Tags: java

I have a java program and it send mails to the users. Since 1 week the mails doesn't been send anymore. I didn't change anything, but now I get this error:

```
connexion failed: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at Launcher$Connexion.<init>(Launcher.java:33)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:52)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1407)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1205)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:322)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:236)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
    at Launcher$Connexion.<init>(Launcher.java:28)
```

I contacted fastmail (mailing server) and they say that the insecure cert is self-signed, and does not expire until 2021.

So I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Could you share the code of your function that should send the email?

Answer (score 1):

Please add DH parameter limits to the certificate of target server. Custom DH parameters by using `openssl dhparam` command should be generated and applied with the `SSLCertificateFile` directive. Please note that the custom DH parameters with a 1024-bit prime will always have precedence over any of the built-in DH parameters.

You should update your Java version to at least version 8 as the 1024-bit restriction should have been lifted to accept 2048-bit parameters.

Please see: [Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)

Comment: but I never had that problem before. Why is it going wrong now ?