# Cannot connect SQL Server DB : Java Windows Service

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

This was all working when we decided to upgrade our SQL Server to 2016 in a new machine. This windows service connects to the database for its functionality but not working when trying to connect with this new Azure VM.

Connection string has integratedSecurity enabled.

Problem: Not able to connect to DB.

What I tried:

- Upgraded Java to 8u201. recompiled the service in the same version.
- Added DHE in java.security file in the disabledAlgorithms.

> ```
> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, *DES*, DHE, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
>     EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
> ```

- Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101440/2017029) to add jars and change security provider.
- Firewalls are disabled.

*Java Version Details*
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

*Here are the traces.*

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair". ClientConnectionId:99c62b92-7f75-41d2-86c2-549ca7bd5d0f)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.init(JdbcTransaction.java:48)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.getConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:89)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForList(SqlMapClientImpl.java:94)
    at com.va.distribution.dao.EventDAO.getEventsByTypeInGroup(EventDAO.java:43)
    at com.va.distribution.util.IntegrationManager.processEventsByType(IntegrationManager.java:57)
    at com.va.distribution.IntegrationJob.runOnce(IntegrationJob.java:67)
    at com.va.StatefulJobAdapter.execute(StatefulJobAdapter.java:24)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:531)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair". ClientConnectionId:99c62b92-7f75-41d2-86c2-549ca7bd5d0f
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
```

---

Comment: Which version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver are you using? And why did you add DHE to the disabledAlgorithms setting?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I have sqljdbc4.jar and upgraded to mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar but didn't make any difference.

Added DHE to disableAlgorithm, assuming this issue would be resolved: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072452

Comment: upgraded JDBC to sqljdbc42.jar... But still the same problem!