# Could not generate DH Keypair Java 1.6.0.11

Tags: java, ssl

I am using Java version string = '1.6.0.11' and while executing receiving the Error Exception caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair

This is a Unix machine and using SSL 2048.  Upgrading Java will solve the issue. I have seen many articles saying that the issue has been fixed. But wanted to confirm if this is an existing issue with older Java version 1.6.0.11

Comment: If you found information that it was fixed, that implies that it was a problem before right? And you already know that upgrading fixes the problem. What exactly are you asking that you don't already know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception.

Comment: What questions do you still have after reading that ticket? The first fix that raises the DH key size to 2048 https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044060 is backported to 6u171. And the second that raises it beyond 2048 bits is backported to 6u181 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051209/could-not-generate-dh-keypair-java-1-6-0-11?noredirect=1#comment98744651_56051209). So you need at least 6u171 or 6u181 depending on the key size used by the site you want to connect to.